# How to call function Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio

I am trying to call function called `connectUser` that takes 2 arguments, name and password and returns id (number)

The problem is that it does not work and I am getting the `NotSupportedException` thrown instead.

```
   int userID;

   [EdmFunction("Model.Store",  "connectUser")]
    public static int connectUser(String loginName, String loginPass)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Direct calls are not supported.");
    }

    private void btnSignIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    userID = (Int32)connectUser(loginName.Text, loginPass.Text);
    }
```

Any idea what is going on? I have tried several tutorials and based on what they say, it should work. But for me it ignores `[EdmFunction("Model.Store",  "connectUser")]` attribute.

Comment: every tutorial i read said that it will ignore throw notsuppported since it is overloaded by [EdmFunction("Model.Store",  "connectUser")]. The code of the function is stored in database. The point of this function is to connect to database, call function and give it attributes and then get the result. I know it connects to database since other functions like creating new user works, but not this one

Answer (score 1):

You get the NotSupportedException because that's what you tell the logic to do :).  `throw new NotSupportedException("Direct calls are not supported.");`.    You need to change to logic to whatever you want the connectUser function to do.

Comment: every tutorial i read said that it will ignore throw notsuppported since it is overloaded by [EdmFunction("Model.Store",  "connectUser")]. The code of the function is stored in database. The point of this function is to connect to database, call function from sql server not to create new one in c# and give it attributes and then get the result. I know it connects to database since other functions like creating new user works, but not this one

Comment: As you see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456847(v=vs.110).aspx the way i am doing it is correct. Do you know what entity framework is and how to use it? Something is wrong but not in "throw new NotSupportedException("Direct calls are not supported.");" since it will be ignored.

Comment: @Ifridius, have you done step 2 of that MSDN article, and put the function definition into your edmx file?

Comment: yeah, i would have no reason to skip steps. procedures works perfectly, but functions does not.